# How to highlight a word in an EditText Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to create an EditText which highlights a part of the entire text present in it.
Eg- when user types a sentence and clicks on submit button, all words words length is greater than 5 should be highlighted.

```
    int counter = 0;
    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) 
       { 
           for(int i = 0; i <  edittext.gettext().tostring().length(); I++) {
                char c = edittext.gettext().tostring().charAt(i);
                if(c == ' '){
                  if(counter>5){
                    // Change that words colour
                    }
                counter=0;
                }
                counter++;
            }
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can highlight parts of `EditText` using `setSelection()`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText#setSelection(int,%20int)

But i don't think there's a way to have multiple separate selections simultaneously.